# HAML Extra Spaces in Textarea

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to be able to decipher.

I'm trying to put text into a textarea in a Rails application. I have a variable with the text in it, which is a multi-line string made from reading the contents of a file. This is the [string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJcTN.png) by the end of the reading of the file. However, the string ends up being put in the text area looking [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDOkk.png).

My guess is that it's due to how the textarea parses the new line character. Replacing all of them with `<br>` or `<br />` renders the tags as plain text. It sounds like there's a simple solution, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

EDIT: Per request, here is the code with the textarea. It's written in HAML, so apologies for that, I couldn't seen to find a HAML to HTML converter that worked (or maybe I'm bad at googling things).

```
%textarea{:name => "user_css", :width => "90%", :rows => "30", :style => "font-family:Courier; font-size:12; white-space:pre-wrap"}
        = css_contents
```

Comment: Can you paste the HTML code here, where you have declared and putting value in the `textarea`?

Comment: Added the code snippet

Comment: Have you tried writing the `%textarea{...}=css_contents` in the same line?

Comment: I've tried it, but it puts =css_contents into the textarea instead of the value of css_contents

Comment: And have you also tried it with `:preserve` filter in HAML? Eg: `%textarea :preserve = css_contents` , all these `%textarea`, `:preserve` and `css_contents` in different lines, 1 tab indented

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand.

Comment: Comments won't let me format here. I'll write it as an answer

Comment: Nvm, I got what you mean. It produces the same results as putting =css_contents on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you could try
1. Use HAML's `:preserve` or `find_and_preserve` helper

```
%textarea{:name => "user_css", :width => "90%", :rows => "30", :style => "font-family:Courier; font-size:12; white-space:pre-wrap"}
   :preserve 
       = css_contents
```

2. Use [HAML's tilde (~)](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#tilde)

```
%textarea{:name => "user_css", :width => "90%", :rows => "30", :style => "font-family:Courier; font-size:12; white-space:pre-wrap"}
   ~ css_contents
```

3. Write it in the same line

```
%textarea{..}= "#{css_contents}"
```